# StringBuilder - Using concatenation vs using append in loop

Tags: java, string, performance, stringbuilder

Wondering what is the best way to use it:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(" Select * from mytable t where ");
for ( Object object : objects ) {
     query.append(" t.field = " + object.field ); // this one OR
     query.append( object.field );                // this one? 
}
```

Not sure which one is recommended to use.

Comment: there is also `query.append(" t.field = ").append(object.field);`

Comment: StringBuilder seems an overkill in this particular case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String builder is much faster, so it's not recommended doing concatenations of more than say 3-4 strings (outside of a loop), and definitely not in loops, I'd suggest you do like this:

```
for ( Object object : objects ) {
     query.append(" t.field = ");
     query.append( object.field ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two separate calls to `append` are better. Behind the scenes, the use of `+` on strings results in a `StringBuilder` being created to do the concatenation. So, you want to either:

1. Concatenate all your strings in one shot using `+` (which doesn't work in your dynamic case), or
2. Use an explicit `StringBuilder` with a call to `append` for each little piece of the string you are building (don't use `+` anywhere).

Answer (score 1):

Use append. However, note that if you are doing relatively few loops (say 10 - 20), then it does not really matter if you use StringBuilder and you may not see any performance improvement.